# Saving Application State in Android

Tags: java, android

I am writing an app where I get all the data from the rest call and display all the data in a custom component list(based on Linear Layout) which is added to a `LinearLayout`. I write this code in `onCreate` of the activity.

The problem is when I switch activity using `startActivity`, and come back to the calling activity (using `startActivity`) then `onCreate` is called again. I see `onPause`, `onStop` called when I call other activity.

Is there any way that I can save the application's state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this question: ["How do I save an android application state"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state/151940#151940).

Edit:
You can also avoid some calls to `onCreate()` by adding a

`android:launchMode="singleTask"`

to your `Activity` in the `AndroidManifest`.

Comment: Thanx it worked :) I used singleInstance. But wondering if there could be any memory issues.